# media player setVoume

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, android-spinner

I have a little problem with my project.

In my project I want to change the volume of media player with the function "setVolume", but it's not working for me.

the volume options are in the spinner.

the code:

```
public void setSpinner() {
    Spinner spine = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spine.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.power, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spine.setAdapter(adapter);
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String s = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    if (s == "minimum") {
        int maxVolume = 50;
        float log1 = (float) (Math.log(maxVolume - 49) / Math.log(maxVolume));
        song.setVolume(1 - log1, 1 - log1);
    }
    if (s == "average") {
        int maxVolume = 50;
        float log1 = (float) (Math.log(maxVolume - 24) / Math.log(maxVolume));
        song.setVolume(1 - log1, 1 - log1);
    }
    if (s == "maximum") {
        int maxVolume = 50;
        float log1 = (float) (Math.log(maxVolume - 1) / Math.log(maxVolume))
        song.setVolume(1 - log1, 1 - log1);
    }
}
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is the problem in this code and fix me please?

Thanks for helpers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        String s = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

        if (s.equals("minimum")) {
            am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
        }else if (s.equals("average")) {
            am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)/2, 0);
        }else if (s.equals("maximum")) {
            am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
        }else {
            //set default volume
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's not working for me, I dont know why but the code isnt comming to the if's in the function.

Comment: for String Variables you must use equals() function